# JPA @ManyToOne References unknown type.

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I have two classes mapped to two separated tables using hibernate/persistence within the play 1.2.4 framework.

The User class has a collection of userRoles as such

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="userId")
@Embedded
public Collection<UserRole> roles;
```

The class, UserRole class has

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="User_ID")
public long userId;
```

Within my mySQL database, the user_roles db has a foreign key from the users db. However, I keep getting the error that

```
@ManyToOne on models.UserRole.userId references an unknown entity: long
```

Comment: If you're using `@ManyToOne`, the datatype of the field it's attached to is expected to be the JPA entity on the other side of the relation: for example, `User`, not `long`.

Comment: And if you're using a OneToMany, it can't be an Embedded at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class UserRole should looks like

```
 @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name="userId")
 public User user;
```

You need to map the entity not the attribute itself.